# Rails application deployment, nginx, unicorn, capistrano socket error

Tags: nginx, socket, unicorn

I am deploying a rails application to a digital ocean VPS. I have followed https://coderwall.com/p/yz8cha . All things done well, but now the browser shows only a blank  page.

Nginx log contains:

```
2014/08/04 03:07:20 [crit] 20550#0: *4 connect() to unix:/var/run/unicorn.testvpsdo.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connectin$
2014/08/04 03:08:39 [crit] 20550#0: *11 connect() to unix:/var/run/unicorn.testvpsdo.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecti$
2014/08/04 03:08:40 [crit] 20550#0: *11 connect() to unix:/var/run/unicorn.testvpsdo.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecti$
2014/08/04 03:08:41 [crit] 20550#0: *11 connect() to unix:/var/run/unicorn.testvpsdo.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecti$
2014/08/04 03:08:41 [crit] 20550#0: *11 connect() to unix:/var/run/unicorn.testvpsdo.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecti$
2014/08/04 03:08:42 [crit] 20550#0: *11 connect() to unix:/var/run/unicorn.testvpsdo.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecti$
2014/08/04 03:08:42 [crit] 20550#0: *14 connect() to unix:/var/run/unicorn.testvpsdo.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecti$
2014/08/04 03:08:42 [crit] 20550#0: *19 connect() to unix:/var/run/unicorn.testvpsdo.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecti$
2014/08/04 04:15:01 [error] 22883#0: *19 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 202.88.237.208, serv$
2014/08/04 04:40:46 [error] 29378#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 202.88.237.208, serve$
2014/08/04 04:45:22 [error] 29378#0: *10 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 202.88.237.208, serv$
2014/08/04 04:49:48 [crit] 31073#0: *1 connect() to unix:/var/run/unicorn.testvpsdo.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connectin$
2014/08/04 04:58:19 [crit] 31073#0: *4 connect() to unix:/var/run/unicorn.testvpsdo.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connectin$
2014/08/04 04:58:38 [crit] 31073#0: *7 connect() to unix:/var/run/unicorn.testvpsdo.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connectin$
2014/08/04 04:59:45 [crit] 32683#0: *1 connect() to unix:/var/run/unicorn.testvpsdo.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connectin$
2014/08/04 05:00:28 [crit] 32683#0: *4 connect() to unix:/var/run/unicorn.testvpsdo.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connectin$
2014/08/04 05:00:29 [crit] 32683#0: *4 connect() to unix:/var/run/unicorn.testvpsdo.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connectin$
2014/08/04 05:08:15 [crit] 32683#0: *8 connect() to unix:/var/run/unicorn.testvpsdo.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connectin$
2014/08/04 05:09:50 [crit] 32683#0: *11 connect() to unix:/var/run/unicorn.testvpsdo.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecti$
2014/08/04 05:30:02 [crit] 32683#0: *14 connect() to unix:/var/run/unicorn.testvpsdo.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecti$
```

I have changed the directory and now error shows:

```
2014/08/04 05:34:18 [emerg] 1985#0: invalid host in upstream "/tmp/unicorn.testvpsdo.sock" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/testvpsdo:2
2014/08/04 05:36:35 [emerg] 2459#0: invalid host in upstream "/tmp/unicorn.testvpsdo.sock" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/testvpsdo:2
```

Nginx config:

```
 upstream unicorn {
     server unix:/tmp/unicorn.testvpsdo.sock fail_timeout=0;
 }

 server {
     listen 80 default_server deferred;
     # server_name example.com;
     root /home/navin/apps/testvpsdo/current/public;

     location ^~ /assets/ {
         gzip_static on;
         expires max;
         add_header Cache-Control public;
     }

     try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;

     location @unicorn {
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
         proxy_redirect off;
         proxy_pass http://unicorn;
     }

     error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
     client_max_body_size 20M;
     keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

I don't know how to fix it even though I searched through many websites.

Comment: Is that all the log says? Just one line? Or can you post the log if there is more info in it.

Comment: Btw, can you check what permission is given to the socket file?

Comment: how to check ?...when I tried to open that .sock file by vim it says admission denied...

Comment: please do `stat -c  '%a' sockfile`. And btw what about the log? Does it say anything else?

Comment: %a means I have to give address of the directory ?

Comment: DUDE!! I did not mean SOCKFILE. please replace with your socket name!

Comment: 777 this is the result I got

Comment: And btw, please post last 20 lines from your nginx log.

Comment: Yes, I added in to question

Comment: Can you confirm if Unicorn is up and running?

Comment: How  to?...actually me too think that there was a problem with unicorn running but unicorn is starts via capistrano I am just a beginner dont know how to check unicorn is running via capistrano

Comment: Hey its okay. Just do `ps aux | grep unicorn` and if you see some processes, then its running. Btw I am very suspicious of the configuration file for nginx. Are you sure that you have `unix:/tmp/unicorn.testvpsdo.sock` in it? the `unix:` part is very important.

Double check that. Did you restart `nginx` after updating the configuration.

Comment: Hi I have manually started unicorn from my project folder now its working and still I have to find how to start the unicorn via capistrano , Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The nginx can not access your socket file due to permissions. Try that:

```
sudo mkdir /var/sockets
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/sockets
sudo mv /tmp/unicorn.testvpsdo.sock /var/sockets/unicorn.testvpsdo.sock
```

Then specify the new socket directory in the nginx.conf and in the unicorn.rb file.
Redeploy and see what happens.